# Area of a graph

Tags: calculus

My question is quite simple, in calculus book there are questions about area of graphs such as:

[image]

or for example

[image]

My question is when the author asks for the area of the region he/she asks ALWAYS about the absolute value of the area? for example the graph bellow has a positive value if we see the area as an absolute value and zero if we consider the bottom part as negative:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: "Area" means the usual geometric quantity (which is positive). The confusion may come from the fact that the definite integral of a function on an interval gives you the area above the axis minus the area below. Note that both areas are positive, but that the one below the axis is being subtracted.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I had this confusion because the value of a integral of a function below the x axis is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the area is always positive.  If you cut your graph off at $x=1.5$, for example, the area is $\int_0^{1.5} 2\sqrt x dx$ where the $2$ accounts for the area below the $x$ axis.

Comment: yes, but the value of a integral of a function below the x axis is negative

Comment: True, so you need to take the absolute value.  Area is positive.